# PuLP takes too much time to run

Tags: python, pulp

I try to use PuLP to solve route optimization problem but it took around 1 hour to finish. I also monitor resources and it seems to use only 1 processor. Is it possible to do a multi-thread or multi-processor? or is there anyway to improve an efficiency?

Here is some source code.

## Variables & Objective function

```
# DECISION VARIABLE X
x_vars = LpVariable.dicts("route",[(i,j,k) for i in job_id for j in job_id for k in truck_id],lowBound=0,upBound=1,cat=LpBinary)

# DECISION VARIABLE Y
y_vars = LpVariable.dicts("work",[(j,k) for j in job_id for k in truck_id],lowBound=0,upBound=1,cat=LpBinary)

# OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
opt_model += lpSum(x_vars[(i,j,k)]*travel_cost[i+'-'+j+'-'+k] for i in job_id for j in job_id for k in truck_id)
```

## Constrains

```
#CONSTRAINTS x[i,j,k] = 0 for all i!=k & j!=k 
for k in truck_id:
    opt_model += lpSum(x_vars[(i,j,k)] for j in job_id for i in yard_id if i!=truck_yard[k]) == 0
    
#CONSTRAINTS
#2
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)
for j in job_id:
    for k in truck_id:
        opt_model += lpSum(x_vars[(i,j,k)] for i in job_id) == y_vars[(j,k)]
```

## Solver

```
Solver_name = 'PULP_CBC_CMD'
solver = pl.getSolver(Solver_name)
results = opt_model.solve(solver)
```

Comment: You might be able to improve a bit w/ multi-threading as suggested in answer.  Realize all of the pre-solve that is done is still single-thread, and that may take some time.  You can also add a small optimality gap, which can sometimes make a huge impact.  Or you could look at reformulating.  There isn't enough code there to make suggestions.  If you want to edit your post and include the rest of the model and a small slice of data, you might get some recommendations.  Large models with lots of combinatoric integer/binary options are just slow in many cases.  :)

Answer (score 1):

At least in PuLP of version 2.6.0, I can execute CBC solver with multi threads by simply adding `threads` parameter to `getSolver`.

```py
Solver_name = 'PULP_CBC_CMD'
solver = pl.getSolver(Solver_name, threads=4)
results = opt_model.solve(solver)
```

https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html?highlight=getsolver#pulp.apis.PULP_CBC_CMD